# Does anyone have a video covering Linq-to-Objects in detail?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I remember seeing a video with Jon Skeet reimplementing Linq-to-Objects a while back but cannot find it now. Could somebody who has that video or one like it please post a link to it here? Thanks

(P.S. I know about the Edulinq blog but only learn well from videos.)

Comment: Are you sure there's a video? I'd imagine he'd posted on the EduLinq series. Have you tried reaching him on G+? He's responded to me there several times... I'm sure he'd let you know if you asked him.

Comment: I don't have a G+ account. I have seen the video though, it was a presentation at a user group. I just can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I listed below two options of learning LINQ from videos:

[Pluralsight - LINQ Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=linq-fundamentals)

[Tekpub - Mastering LINQ](http://shop.tekpub.com/products/linq)

You must pay to view the series of videos above. I think it's worth paying the money, but this is my opinion.

An alternative to the payed version of videos would be visiting [Jon Skeet website](http://csharpindepth.com/).

You can find some resources on the [Talks](http://csharpindepth.com/Talks.aspx) page.
I think **Reading, November 22nd 2008: LINQ to Obejcts in 60 minutes** will help you. 
It offers source code, video and slide deck.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you were looking for the recording of his talk at Copenhagen? He mentions it [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/11/19/copenhagen-c-talk-videos-now-up.aspx). He also has a [list](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/30/returning-from-copenhagen.aspx) of the topics he spoke on, it seems to include Linq to Objects as well as some .NET/C# topics that are often used in conjunction with Linq.

[This is a link](http://www.msdncommunity.dk/udviklere/webcasts) to the video on MSDN, but I cannot connect to MSDN at the moment, I will look again in a few to see if I can find another version or if I can connect then.

Comment: Whilst I can't get to them now, I think you've come closest, so have some rep.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any video which is anything like Edulinq... although if there's enough interest, I could see if I could talk Rob into making it into a new Tekpub series. I'm sure I'd enjoy doing it, if folks think it would be useful. I know there are already LINQ videos available (including one from Tekpub) but not going into that much detail in LINQ to Objects and looking at a sample implementation.

Although I've given a couple of talks doing everything I can in an hour, they didn't really go into very much detail - they were for the *flavour* of LINQ rather than the detail.

Comment: Those were the talks I think, remember... flavour to you is detail to the rest of the world.

Comment: a Jon Skeet answer with zero upvotes? amazing!

Comment: I know, that's a rarity. @Jon Please please do it. It would be the first video series I would ever pay for! :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok here are a few basic ones, the 3 videos on the left side with "linq" in the title on the [Microsoft Linq page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594).

There's also a page here:

[LINQ Videos](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_LINQ.aspx)

This has some videos that are more detailed, some stuff on aggregates and groups which touches on things like Group() and SelectMany() (that one is in VB, if you're into that sort of thing), and an interesting interview with Anders Hejlsberg (the architect of LINQ).

Comment: They're far too basic, sorry. I need something that will give me a look into the internals and cover most of the trickier operators, like SelectMany.

Comment: I edited to have some additional videos. Hope they help.